# Function To Create Regex Matching a Number Range

Tags: php, regex, function, integer, range

I am working with the Amazon Mechanical Turk API and it will only allow me to use regular expressions to filter a field of data.

I would like to input an integer range to a function, such as 256-311 or 45-1233, and return a regex that would match only that range.

A regex matching 256-321 would be:

```
\b((25[6-9])|(2[6-9][0-9])|(3[0-1][0-9])|(32[0-1]))\b
```

That part is fairly easy, but I am having trouble with the loop to create this regex.

I am trying to build a function defined like this:

```
function getRangeRegex( int fromInt, int toInt)
{

      return regexString;
}
```

I looked all over the web and I am surprised that it doesn't look like anyone has solved this in the past.  It is a difficult problem...

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Some people don't understand that others work with APIs...  and some APIs will only allow regex filtering.

Comment: not sure if you're using my suggestion, but it had a bug (the range `180-195` returned an incorrect regex). I've fixed it however (the same answer).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [a regular expression generator for number ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512037/a-regular-expression-generator-for-number-ranges)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a quick hack:

```php
<?php

function regex_range($from, $to) {

  if($from < 0 || $to < 0) {
    throw new Exception("Negative values not supported"); 
  }

  if($from > $to) {
    throw new Exception("Invalid range $from..$to, from > to"); 
  }

  $ranges = array($from);
  $increment = 1;
  $next = $from;
  $higher = true;

  while(true) {

    $next += $increment;

    if($next + $increment > $to) {
      if($next <= $to) {
        $ranges[] = $next;
      }
      $increment /= 10;
      $higher = false;
    }
    else if($next % ($increment*10) === 0) {
      $ranges[] = $next;
      $increment = $higher ? $increment*10 : $increment/10;
    }

    if(!$higher && $increment < 10) {
      break;
    }
  }

  $ranges[] = $to + 1;

  $regex = '/^(?:';

  for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($ranges) - 1; $i++) {
    $str_from = (string)($ranges[$i]);
    $str_to = (string)($ranges[$i + 1] - 1);

    for($j = 0; $j < strlen($str_from); $j++) {
      if($str_from[$j] == $str_to[$j]) {
        $regex .= $str_from[$j];
      }
      else {
        $regex .= "[" . $str_from[$j] . "-" . $str_to[$j] . "]";
      }
    }
    $regex .= "|";
  }

  return substr($regex, 0, strlen($regex)-1) . ')$/';
}

function test($from, $to) {
  try {
    printf("%-10s %s\n", $from . '-' . $to, regex_range($from, $to));
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
  }
}

test(2, 8);
test(5, 35);
test(5, 100);
test(12, 1234);
test(123, 123);
test(256, 321);
test(256, 257);
test(180, 195);
test(2,1);
test(-2,4);

?>
```

which produces:

```
2-8        /^(?:[2-7]|8)$/
5-35       /^(?:[5-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-5])$/
5-100      /^(?:[5-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)$/
12-1234    /^(?:1[2-9]|[2-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|1[0-2][0-3][0-4])$/
123-123    /^(?:123)$/
256-321    /^(?:25[6-9]|2[6-9][0-9]|3[0-2][0-1])$/
256-257    /^(?:256|257)$/
180-195    /^(?:18[0-9]|19[0-5])$/
Invalid range 2..1, from > to
Negative values not supported
```

Not properly tested, use at your own risk!

And yes, the generated regex could be written more compact in many cases, but I leave that as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: @BartKiers - I liked this so much I adapted it into javascript (as seen below - with credit of course).

Comment: Great answer - works with text ranges as well - see my answer to this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347381/regular-expression-to-validate-excel-cell with credit to @BartKiers

Comment: While I like this solution, I have encountered an issue when the range contains at least two decades of numbers above `100`. @BartKiers, you can see this even in `256-321` from your example. The final part of the regex `3[0-2][0-1]` does not match e.g. `309`, but it should, therefore the regex should be `3[0-1][0-9]|32[0-1]`. If the end number would be `318`, the final range should be `30[0-9]|31[0-1]`. I’ll try to fix it, but there might be someone who comes with a solution quicker which might be better than mine. :)

Comment: `^(?:[2-7]|8)$` is awkward.

Comment: @mickmackusa hence my comment: "And yes, the generated regex could be written more compact in many cases". The thing is generated, after all.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else who, like me, was looking for the javascript version of the great @Bart Kiers's production above

```
//Credit: Bart Kiers 2011
function regex_range(from, to){
        if(from < 0 || to < 0) {
            //throw new Exception("Negative values not supported"); 
            return null;
        }
        if(from > to) {
            //throw new Exception("Invalid range from..to, from > to"); 
            return null;
        }

        var ranges = [];
        ranges.push(from);
        var increment = 1;
        var next = from;
        var higher = true;

        while(true){
            next += increment;
            if(next + increment > to) {
                if(next <= to) {
                    ranges.push(next);
                }
                increment /= 10;
                higher = false;
            }else{ 
                if(next % (increment*10) == 0) {
                    ranges.push(next);
                    increment = higher ? increment*10 : increment/10;
                }
            }

            if(!higher && increment < 10) {
                break;
            }
        }

        ranges.push(to + 1);
        var regex = '/^(?:';

        for(var i = 0; i < ranges.length - 1; i++) {
            var str_from = ranges[i];
            str_from = str_from.toString();
            var str_to = ranges[i + 1] - 1;
            str_to = str_to.toString();
            for(var j = 0; j < str_from.length; j++) {
                if(str_from[j] == str_to[j]) {
                    regex += str_from[j];
                }
                else {
                    regex += "[" + str_from[j] + "-" + str_to[j] + "]";
                }
            }
            regex += "|";
        }

        return regex.substr(0, regex.length - 1 ) + ')$/';
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP Port of [RegexNumericRangeGenerator](https://github.com/erwinyusrizal/RegexNumericRangeGenerator)

```
class RegexRangeNumberGenerator {

    static function parse($min, $max, $MatchWholeWord = FALSE, $MatchWholeLine = FALSE, $MatchLeadingZero = FALSE) {
        if (!is_int($min) || !is_int($max) || $min > $max || $min < 0 || $max < 0) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        if ($min == $max) {
            return self::parseIntoPattern($min, $MatchWholeWord, $MatchWholeLine, $MatchLeadingZero);
        }
        $s = [];
        $x = self::parseStartRange($min, $max);
        foreach ($x as $o) {
            $s[] = self::parseEndRange($o[0], $o[1]);
        }
        $n = self::reformatArray($s);
        $h = self::parseIntoRegex($n);
        return self::parseIntoPattern($h, $MatchWholeWord, $MatchWholeLine, $MatchLeadingZero);
    }

    static private function parseIntoPattern($t, $MatchWholeWord = FALSE, $MatchWholeLine = FALSE, $MatchLeadingZero = FALSE) {
        $r = ((is_array($t)) ? implode("|", $t) : $t);
        return (($MatchWholeLine && $MatchLeadingZero) ? "^0*(" . $r . ")$" : (($MatchLeadingZero) ? "0*(" . $r . ")" : (($MatchWholeLine) ? "^(" . $r . ")$" : (($MatchWholeWord) ? "\\b(" . $r . ")\\b" : "(" . $r . ")"))));
    }

    static private function parseIntoRegex($t) {
        if (!is_array($t)) {
            throw new Exception("Argument needs to be an array!");
        }
        $r = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($t); $i++) {
            $e = str_split($t[$i][0]);
            $n = str_split($t[$i][1]);
            $s = "";
            $o = 0;
            $h = "";
            for ($a = 0; $a < count($e); $a++) {
                if ($e[$a] === $n[$a]) {
                    $h .= $e[$a];
                } else {
                    if ((intval($e[$a]) + 1) === intval($n[$a])) {
                        $h .= "[" . $e[$a] . $n[$a] . "]";
                    } else {
                        if ($s === ($e[$a] . $n[$a])) {
                            $o++;
                        }
                        $s = $e[$a] . $n[$a];
                        if ($a == (count($e) - 1)) {
                            $h .= (($o > 0) ? "{" . ($o + 1) . "}" : "[" . $e[$a] . "-" . $n[$a] . "]");
                        } else {
                            if ($o === 0) {
                                $h .= "[" . $e[$a] . "-" . $n[$a] . "]";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $r[] = $h;
        }
        return $r;
    }

    static private function reformatArray($t) {
        $arrReturn = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($t); $i++) {
            $page = count($t[$i]) / 2;
            for ($a = 0; $a < $page; $a++) {
                $arrReturn[] = array_slice($t[$i], (2 * $a), 2);
            }
        }
        return $arrReturn;
    }

    static private function parseStartRange($t, $r) {
        if (strlen($t) === strlen($r)) {
            return [[$t, $r]];
        }
        $break = pow(10, strlen($t)) - 1;
        return array_merge([[$t, $break]], self::parseStartRange($break + 1, $r));
    }

    static private function parseEndRange($t, $r) {
        if (strlen($t) == 1) {
            return [$t, $r];
        }
        if (str_repeat("0", strlen($t)) === "0" . substr($t, 1)) {
            if (str_repeat("0", strlen($r)) == "9" . substr($r, 1)) {
                return [$t, $r];
            }
            if ((int) substr($t, 0, 1) < (int) substr($r, 0, 1)) {
                $e = intval(substr($r, 0, 1) . str_repeat("0", strlen($r) - 1)) - 1;
                return array_merge([$t, self::strBreakPoint($e)], self::parseEndRange(self::strBreakPoint($e + 1), $r));
            }
        }
        if (str_repeat("9", strlen($r)) === "9" . substr($r, 1) && (int) substr($t, 0, 1) < (int) substr($r, 0, 1)) {
            $e = intval(intval((int) substr($t, 0, 1) + 1) . "" . str_repeat("0", strlen($r) - 1)) - 1;
            return array_merge(self::parseEndRange($t, self::strBreakPoint($e)), [self::strBreakPoint($e + 1), $r]);
        }
        if ((int) substr($t, 0, 1) < (int) substr($r, 0, 1)) {
            $e = intval(intval((int) substr($t, 0, 1) + 1) . "" . str_repeat("0", strlen($r) - 1)) - 1;
            return array_merge(self::parseEndRange($t, self::strBreakPoint($e)), self::parseEndRange(self::strBreakPoint($e + 1), $r));
        }
        $a = (int) substr($t, 0, 1);
        $o = self::parseEndRange(substr($t, 1), substr($r, 1));
        $h = [];
        for ($u = 0; $u < count($o); $u++) {
            $h[] = ($a . $o[$u]);
        }
        return $h;
    }

    static private function strBreakPoint($t) {
        return str_pad($t, strlen(($t + 1)), "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
}
```

Test Results

```
2-8         ^([2-8])$
5-35        ^([5-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-5])$
5-100       ^([5-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|100)$
12-1234     ^(1[2-9]|[2-9][0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2}|9[0-8][0-9]|99[0-9]|1[01][0-9]{2}|12[0-2][0-9]|123[0-4])$
123-123     ^(123)$
256-321     ^(25[6-9]|2[6-9][0-9]|3[01][0-9]|32[01])$
256-257     ^(25[67])$
180-195     ^(18[0-9]|19[0-5])$
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason it has to be regex? can not do some thing like this:

```
if ($number >= 256 && $number <= 321){
   // do something 
}
```

Update:

There is an easy but ugly way to do it using [range](http://php.net/range):

```
function getRangeRegex($from, $to)
{
    $range = implode('|', range($from, $to));

    // returns: 256|257|...|321
    return $range;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but there is a string length limit in the API that would be reached by listing every number.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, the excelent @Bart Kiers's code (and JS version of Travis J) in some cases it fails. For example:

```
12-1234    /^(?:1[2-9]|[2-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|1[0-2][0-3][0-4])$/
```

does not match "1229", "1115", "1[0-2][0-2]**[5-9]**"

Comment: oops, I’ve just noticed you noticed this first (I’ve just [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710236/function-to-create-regex-matching-a-number-range/11874428#comment118997167_6714033) on this ;p). I am trying to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

That actually has been done already.

Have a look at [this](http://kuxyz.blogspot.com/2011/03/generating-regexes-that-match-numeric.html) site. It contains a link to a python script that generates these regex's for you automagically.

Comment: That looks impressive.  Any php resources?

Comment: I can't find any ready-made php script atm. But I'm willing to give it a try to convert the python script to PHP. Although I can't promise it'll be ready in 5 minutes..

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is duplicated from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130429/regex-matching-number-in-range/22131040#22131040). I've also made it into a [blog post](http://aliteralmind.wordpress.com/2014/03/02/regex_numeric_range/)*

---

### Using regular expressions to validate a numeric range

To be clear: When a simple if statement will suffice

```
if(num < -2055  ||  num > 2055)  {
   throw  new IllegalArgumentException("num (" + num + ") must be between -2055 and 2055");
}
```

using regular expressions for validating numeric ranges is not recommended.

In addition, since regular expressions analyze strings, numbers must first be translated to a string before they can be tested (an exception is when the number happens to already be a string, such as when getting user input from the console).

(To ensure the string is a number to begin with, you could use `org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils#isNumber(s)`)

Despite this, figuring out how to validate number ranges with regular expressions is interesting and instructive.

### A one number range

**Rule:** A number must be exactly `15`.

The simplest range there is. A regex to match this is

```
\b15\b
```

Word boundaries are necessary to avoid matching the `15` inside of `8215242`.

### A two number range

**The rule:** The number must be between `15` and `16`. Three possible regexes:

```
\b(15|16)\b
\b1(5|6)\b
\b1[5-6]\b
```

### A number range "mirrored" around zero

**The rule:** The number must be between `-12` and `12`.

Here is a regex for `0` through `12`, positive-only:

```
\b(\d|1[0-2])\b
```

Free-spaced:

```
\b(         //The beginning of a word (or number), followed by either
   \d       //   Any digit 0 through 9
|           //Or
   1[0-2]   //   A 1 followed by any digit between 0 and 2.
)\b         //The end of a word
```

Making this work for both negative and positive is as simple as adding an optional dash at the start:

```
-?\b(\d|1[0-2])\b
```

(This assumes no inappropriate characters precede the dash.)

To *forbid* negative numbers, a negative lookbehind is necessary:

```
(?<!-)\b(\d|1[0-2])\b
```

Leaving the lookbehind out would cause the `11` in `-11` to match. (The first example in this post should have this added.)

### Note: `\d` versus `[0-9]`

In order to be compatible with all regex flavors, all `\d`-s should be changed to `[0-9]`. For example, .NET considers non ASCII numbers, such as those in different languages, as legal values for `\d`. Except for in the last example, for brevity, it's left as `\d`.

*(With thanks to [TimPietzcker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20670/tim-pietzcker) at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com))*

#### Three digits, with all but the first digit equal to zero

**Rule:** Must be between `0` and `400`.

A possible regex:

```
(?<!-)\b([1-3]?\d{1,2}|400)\b
```

Free spaced:

```
   (?<!-)          //Something not preceded by a dash
   \b(             //Word-start, followed by either
      [1-3]?       //   No digit, or the digit 1, 2, or 3
         \d{1,2}   //   Followed by one or two digits (between 0 and 9)
   |               //Or
      400          //   The number 400
   )\b             //Word-end
```

Another possibility that should *never be used*:

```
\b(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|60|61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68|69|70|71|72|73|74|75|76|77|78|79|80|81|82|83|84|85|86|87|88|89|90|91|92|93|94|95|96|97|98|99|100|101|102|103|104|105|106|107|108|109|110|111|112|113|114|115|116|117|118|119|120|121|122|123|124|125|126|127|128|129|130|131|132|133|134|135|136|137|138|139|140|141|142|143|144|145|146|147|148|149|150|151|152|153|154|155|156|157|158|159|160|161|162|163|164|165|166|167|168|169|170|171|172|173|174|175|176|177|178|179|180|181|182|183|184|185|186|187|188|189|190|191|192|193|194|195|196|197|198|199|200|201|202|203|204|205|206|207|208|209|210|211|212|213|214|215|216|217|218|219|220|221|222|223|224|225|226|227|228|229|230|231|232|233|234|235|236|237|238|239|240|241|242|243|244|245|246|247|248|249|250|251|252|253|254|255|256|257|258|259|260|261|262|263|264|265|266|267|268|269|270|271|272|273|274|275|276|277|278|279|280|281|282|283|284|285|286|287|288|289|290|291|292|293|294|295|296|297|298|299|300|301|302|303|304|305|306|307|308|309|310|311|312|313|314|315|316|317|318|319|320|321|322|323|324|325|326|327|328|329|330|331|332|333|334|335|336|337|338|339|340|341|342|343|344|345|346|347|348|349|350|351|352|353|354|355|356|357|358|359|360|361|362|363|364|365|366|367|368|369|370|371|372|373|374|375|376|377|378|379|380|381|382|383|384|385|386|387|388|389|390|391|392|393|394|395|396|397|398|399|400)\b
```

#### Final example: Four digits, mirrored around zero, that does not end with zeros.

**Rule:** Must be between `-2055` and `2055`

*This is from a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22130429/2736496) on stackoverflow.*

Regex:

```
-?\b(20(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1?[0-9]{1,3})\b
```

Free-spaced:

```
   -?                 //Optional dash
   \b(                //Followed by word boundary, followed by either of the following
      20(             //   "20", followed by either
         5[0-5]       //      A "5" followed by a digit 0-5
      |               //   or
         [0-4][0-9]   //      A digit 0-4, followed by any digit
      )
   |                  //OR
      1?[0-9]{1,3}    //   An optional "1", followed by one through three digits (0-9)
   )\b                //Followed by a word boundary.
```

Here is a visual representation of this regex:

[image]

And here you can try it out yourself: [Debuggex demonstration](https://www.debuggex.com/r/KJvkvrmMcgLKgf-v)

*(With thanks to [PlasmaPower](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3352674/plasmapower) on stackoverflow for the debugging assistance.)*

### Final note

Depending on what you are [capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), it is likely that all sub-groups should be made into non-capture groups. For example, this:

```
(-?\b(?:20(?:5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1?[0-9]{1,3})\b)
```

Instead of this:

```
-?\b(20(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1?[0-9]{1,3})\b
```

#### Example Java implementation

```
  import  java.util.Scanner;
  import  java.util.regex.Matcher;
  import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
  import  org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils;
/**
  <P>Confirm a user-input number is a valid number by reading a string an testing it is numeric before converting it to an it--this loops until a valid number is provided.</P>

  <P>{@code java UserInputNumInRangeWRegex}</P>
 **/
public class UserInputNumInRangeWRegex  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {

      int num = -1;
      boolean isNum = false;

      int iRangeMax = 2055;

      //"": Dummy string, to reuse matcher
      Matcher mtchrNumNegThrPos = Pattern.compile("-?\\b(20(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1?[0-9]{1,3})\\b").matcher("");

      do  {
         System.out.print("Enter a number between -" + iRangeMax + " and " + iRangeMax + ": ");
         String strInput = (new Scanner(System.in)).next();
         if(!NumberUtils.isNumber(strInput))  {
            System.out.println("Not a number. Try again.");
         }  else if(!mtchrNumNegThrPos.reset(strInput).matches())  {
            System.out.println("Not in range. Try again.");
         }  else  {
            //Safe to convert
            num = Integer.parseInt(strInput);
            isNum = true;
         }
      }  while(!isNum);

      System.out.println("Number: " + num);
   }
}
```

Output

```
[C:\java_code\]java UserInputNumInRangeWRegex
Enter a number between -2055 and 2055: tuhet
Not a number. Try again.
Enter a number between -2055 and 2055: 283837483
Not in range. Try again.
Enter a number between -2055 and 2055: -200000
Not in range. Try again.
Enter a number between -2055 and 2055: -300
Number: -300
```

Comment: Rather than bloating SO with a redundant answer on the site, it would be better if you just added a referencing link in a comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've converted Bart Kiers's answer into C++. The function takes two integers as an input and generates the regular expression for the number range.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::string regex_range(int from, int to);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string regex = regex_range(1,100);

    std::cout << regex << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

std::string regex_range(int from, int to) //Credit: Bart Kiers 2011
{
    if(from < 0 || to < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Negative values not supported. Exiting." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if(from > to)
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid range, from > to. Exiting." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    std::vector<int> ranges;
    ranges.push_back(from);
    int increment = 1;
    int next = from;
    bool higher = true;

    while(true)
    {

        next += increment;

        if(next + increment > to)
        {
            if(next <= to)
            {
                ranges.push_back(next);
            }
            increment /= 10;
            higher = false;
        }
        else if(next % (increment*10) == 0)
        {
            ranges.push_back(next);
            increment = higher ? increment*10 : increment/10;
        }

        if(!higher && (increment < 10))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    ranges.push_back(to + 1);
    std::string regex("^(?:");

    for(int i = 0; i < ranges.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        int current_from = ranges.at(i);
        std::string str_from = std::to_string(current_from);
        int current_to = ranges.at(i + 1) - 1;
        std::string str_to = std::to_string(current_to);
        for(int j = 0; j < str_from.length(); j++)
        {
            if(str_from.at(j) == str_to.at(j))
            {
                std::string str_from_at_j(&str_from.at(j));
                regex.append(str_from_at_j);
            }
            else
            {
                std::string str_from_at_j(&str_from.at(j));
                std::string str_to_at_j(&str_to.at(j));

                regex.append("[");
                regex.append(str_from_at_j);
                regex.append("-");
                regex.append(str_to_at_j);
                regex.append("]");
            }
        }
        regex.append("|");
    }
    regex = regex.substr(0, regex.length() - 1);
    regex.append(")$");
    return regex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have [encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710236/function-to-create-regex-matching-a-number-range/11874428#comment118997167_6714033) the same issue as @EmilianoT already [reported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57445378/3408342), I tried to fix it, but in the end I opted for porting the [PHP port](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57446672/3408342) of [RegexNumericRangeGenerator](https://github.com/erwinyusrizal/RegexNumericRangeGenerator) (ported by @EmilianoT), although not in a class. I am not quite happy with this JS port, as all `toString()` and `parseInt()` methods could be still optimised (they might be somewhere unnecessary), but it works for all cases.

I thing I changed are the parameters. I replaced `parse($min, $max, $MatchWholeWord = FALSE, $MatchWholeLine = FALSE, $MatchLeadingZero = FALSE)` with `parse(min, max, width = 0, prefix = '', suffix = '')`, which gives it more options (some might want to put the regex into slashes, others want to match the line [`prefix = '^'; suffix = '$'`], etc). Also I wanted to be able to configure the width of the number (`width = 3` → `000`, `001`, `052`, `800`, `1000`, ...).

I replaced my previous answer, as it does not work all the time. If one wants to read it, they can see it in the answer history.

```js
function parse(min, max, width = 0, prefix = '', suffix = '') {
  if (! Number.isInteger(min) || ! Number.isInteger(max) || min > max || min < 0 || max < 0) {
    return false
  }

  if (min == max) {
    return parseIntoPattern(min, prefix, suffix)
  }

  let x = parseStartRange(min, max)
  let s = []

  x.forEach(o => {
    s.push(parseEndRange(o[0], o[1]))
  })

  let n = reformatArray(s)
  let h = parseIntoRegex(n, width)

  return parseIntoPattern(h, prefix, suffix)
}

function parseIntoPattern(t, prefix = '', suffix = '') {
  let r = Array.isArray(t) ? t.join('|') : t
  return prefix + '(' + r + ')' + suffix
}

function parseIntoRegex(t, width = 0) {
  if (! Array.isArray(t)) {
    throw new Error('Argument needs to be an array!')
  }

  let r = []

  for (let i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    let e = t[i][0].split('')
    let n = t[i][1].split('')
    let s = ''
    let o = 0
    let h = ''

    for (let a = 0; a < e.length; a++) {
      if (e[a] === n[a]) {
        h += e[a]
      } else if (parseInt(e[a]) + 1 === parseInt(n[a])) {
        h += '[' + e[a] + n[a] + ']'
      } else {
        if (s === e[a] + n[a]) {
          o++
        }

        s = e[a] + n[a]

        if (a == e.length - 1) {
          h += o > 0 ? '{' + (o + 1) + '}' : '[' + e[a] + '-' + n[a] + ']'
        } else if (o === 0) {
          h += '[' + e[a] + '-' + n[a] + ']'
        }
      }
    }

    if (e.length < width) {
      h = '0'.repeat(width - e.length, '0') + h
    }

    r.push(h)
  }

  return r
}

function reformatArray(t) {
  let arrReturn = []

  for (let i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    let page = t[i].length / 2

    for (let a = 0; a < page; a++) {
      arrReturn.push(t[i].slice(2 * a))
    }
  }

  return arrReturn
}

function parseStartRange(t, r) {
  t = t.toString()
  r = r.toString()

  if (t.length === r.length) {
    return [[t, r]]
  }

  let breakOut = 10 ** t.length - 1
  return [[t, breakOut.toString()]].concat(parseStartRange(breakOut + 1, r))
}

function parseEndRange(t, r) {
  if (t.length == 1) {
    return [t, r]
  }

  if ('0'.repeat(t.length) === '0' + t.substr(1)) {
    if ('0'.repeat(r.length) == '9' + r.substr(1)) {
      return [t, r]
    }

    if (parseInt(t.toString().substr(0, 1)) < parseInt(r.toString().substr(0, 1))) {
      let e = parseInt(r.toString().substr(0, 1) + '0'.repeat(r.length - 1)) - 1
      return [t, strBreakPoint(e)].concat(parseEndRange(strBreakPoint(e + 1), r))
    }
  }

  if ('9'.repeat(r.length) === '9' + r.toString().substr(1) && parseInt(t.toString().substr(0, 1)) < parseInt(r.toString().substr(0, 1))) {
    let e = parseInt(parseInt(parseInt(t.toString().substr(0, 1)) + 1) + '0'.repeat(r.length - 1)) - 1
    return parseEndRange(t, strBreakPoint(e)).concat(strBreakPoint(e + 1), r)
  }

  if (parseInt(t.toString().substr(0, 1)) < parseInt(r.toString().substr(0, 1))) {
    let e = parseInt(parseInt(parseInt(t.toString().substr(0, 1)) + 1) + '0'.repeat(r.length - 1)) - 1
    return parseEndRange(t, strBreakPoint(e)).concat(parseEndRange(strBreakPoint(e + 1), r))
  }

  let a = parseInt(t.toString().substr(0, 1))
  let o = parseEndRange(t.toString().substr(1), r.toString().substr(1))
  let h = []

  for (let u = 0; u < o.length; u++) {
    h.push(a + o[u])
  }

  return h
}

function strBreakPoint(t) {
  return t.toString().padStart((parseInt(t) + 1).toString().length, '0')
}
```