# Regular expression: "string+number+string"

Tags: regex

sorry about simple question.

I need to check if the string include, this pattern.

```
somestring 532:
```

for more information,  string + one space + number > 0 + ':'

Comment: an what did you try already?

Comment: I've tried RegExp("somestring [0-9] :")

Comment: what if your somestring got an space ?

Comment: I suggest we remove the downvotes and simply ask the OP to include what he has tried, in the question.

Comment: ok sorry, i'm fairly bad in english so i cannot describe my question enough. i'll delete this question.

Comment: We understand what you mean. Simply adding what you have tried and why it didn't work will be sufficient to create a good question.

Comment: yep honestly this question is my bad. I was struggled to get profer Regular expression, so I asked without any descritption. I apologize my bad

Comment: This is partially addressed in the [StackOverflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496). Relevant answers: [Validating a string is a number](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4247184/578411) and [Validating a number falls within a min-max range (such as 1-31)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22131040/2736496). Section: "Advanced regex-fu > Common validation tasks > Numeric", which is about 2/3 down.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with following regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+ [1-9]\d*:$
```

Comment: Small typo. You need `[a-zA-Z]` but otherwise correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

`([a-zA-Z]+)\s([1-9]\d*):`

Comment: This will match with a digit of 0 before the :

Comment: @dcharms, Thank you. Updated answer accordingly.