# how can I generate REGEX for value > 2900

Tags: regex

how can I generate REGEX for value > `2900.00` I used the formula below but it seems it is not working

```
(^[2-9][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{5,})(\.[0-9]+)$
```

Comment: try to use different method. any digit point any digit repeat.

Comment: Here is an answer I wrote on using regular expressions to validate a numeric range: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22131040/2736496.

Comment: Why would you want to use a regular expression for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you

```
/^29\d{2}\.[0-9][1-9]|[3-9]\d{3}\.\d{2}|[1-9]\d{4,}\.\d{2}$/
```

**Explanation**

4 digit `>=` 2900.01 — `29\d{2}\.[0-9][1-9]`

OR

4 digit `>=` 3000.00 — `[3-9]\d{3}\.\d{2}`

OR

Any 5+ digit — `[1-9]\d{4,}\.\d{2}`

---

Personally, I think these kinds of regexp are kind of silly, though. Can't we just parse it and compare the result numerically?