# C# Regex for 0-100

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a field on my c# mvc model to hold percentage - I want to use RegEx data annotation to validate that the field only contains values of 0-100

I seen a similar Regex here - `^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000)$` - that matches values 1-1000 - I am not sure of the correct ammendment to make it fit for my scenario?

I tried something like below `^([0-9][0-9]{0,2}|100)$` but not working as expected?

Comment: ^([1-9][0-9]{0,1}|100)$

Comment: ^([0-9][0-9]{0,1}|100)$ ?

Comment: ^([0-9][0-9]{0,1}|100)$ and ^([1-9][0-9]?|100)$ both should work

Comment: @vikas first option would validate value 01, which may not be what OP is after. Second option does not validate value 0.

Comment: Do you know `RangeValidator`?http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22130429) might also be a good read.

Comment: *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know,
I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* --  Jamie Zawinski

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the below pattern to match the digits from 0 to 100,

```
^(?:100|[1-9]?[0-9])$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sL8vF1/4)

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `(?:)` Non-capturing group which only does a matching operation.
- `100` Matches the string 100.
- `|` Logical OR operator used to OR two regexes.
- `[1-9]?` Matches one of any digit from the range 1 to 9. `?` after the character class makes it optional.
- `[0-9]` Matches one of any digit from the range 0 to 9.
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end of the line.

Comment: +1, Though the shortest approach would be `^(?!0)\d{3}$`.

Comment: This solution is in excess of 500% more computationally intensive than a simple `TryParse` and range check.  Don't write validation code like this.  It's ugly, nonintuitive, hard to read, and incredibly inefficient.  There is no sensible reason to choose regex to solve this problem.

Comment: @J... [There is.](https://www.thc.org/root/phun/unmaintain.html)

Comment: @J... - I am wanting to make use of Data Annotations above the property in Question - hence using RegEx

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat There is a range attribute you can use that is rather more appropriate - again, why regex?

Comment: @J... I think originally I had used Range but my requirement for percentage field is whole numbers onlly - I belive Range allowed 2.5 for example which I did not want

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat if it is an integer property then it cannot have a non-integer component.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you want to validate it using a regex? I think it would be easier to just use `.TryParse` and a range check:

```
bool Validate(string input) {
  int x;
  return int.TryParse(input, out x) && x >= 0 && x <= 100;
}
```

Also more readable if you ask me …

Comment: @AvinashRaj I mean they constitute an inappropriate, albeit technically correct, solution to the problem.  You can describe a correct technique for using a chainsaw to open a tin of soup, but it remains nevertheless an unsuitable tool (and approach) for the job.

Answer (score 2):

If the percentage field on your model is of type `int`, you could more easily use the Range annotation:

```
[Range(0, 100)]
public int Percentage { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like so should work: `^([0-9]{1,2}|100)$`. That being said, please refrain from using regular expressions for number evaluation. You should use numeric operators for this purpose.

Comment: This does not validate value 0.

Comment: @Dialecticus: Sorry my bad. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Right, but now regex will validate value 01, which may not be what OP was after.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

^(([1-9]\d?)|100)$
This would ensure that

There is at least one digit

That multi-digit numbers start in a digit other than zero

That the only allowed three-digit number is 100.

Comment: This does not validate value 0.

Comment: just change the 1 to 0.. it should work fine... :) cheers n vote please..

Comment: No. Wont upvote current incorrect answer. And if I replace 1-9 with 0-9 value 01 would be validated, which may not be what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
^([1-9]?[0-9]|100)$
```