# Validate Number if it is in certain range using JavaScript RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, pattern-matching

Ok I have looked on a number of links regarding how to validate an input string whether it is a number and within certain range but seems like I am not understanding it clearly.

Can somebody explain me in an easy manner, considering me a novice, how using JavaScript's Regular Expressions I can validate an input string if it is a number and between the range of 1 to 5000. Input string cannot be empty and 0.

Please do explain your RegExp magic pattern.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to use Regular Expressions and can't check the value in a regular conditional? Like `if (val >= 1 && val < 5000)`?

Comment: can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: I m using a React plugin where unfortunately I have to make use of regular expression to validate a number. Search 'Subschema' on google.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23383708/3832970) will help you understand how to build such patterns. The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S878Y/9/) to test your pattern is also there.