# Regular expression which validates whether the number is in between 0.00 to 20.00

Tags: javascript, regex

I have searched a lot  also tried but it is not working for me.
I am using java script.

Comment: Share your code. What have you tried?

Comment: update your question with code. what regular expression you are trying?

Comment: Are the boundaries `0.00` and `20.00` *included* or *excluded*? Is `1.9999999999` a valid input or you require *exactly two* digits after decimal point? Could, please, you provide *some examples*?

Comment: using regular expressions for validating numeric ranges is not recommended. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130429/using-regular-expressions-to-validate-a-numeric-range

Comment: I require only exactly 2 digits after decimal point

Comment: @Bikram Sahu: and what about *leading zero*? E.g. `05.00` is it a valid input?

Answer (score 1):

Providing that

1. *Both* borders are included (so `0.00` and `20.00` are valid)
2. Two digits after the decimal point are *mandatory* (`5` in invalid, but `5.00` is OK)
3. *Leading zeros* are invalid (so `05.00` is invalid)

the regular expression can be

```
(^1?[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}$)|(^20\.00$)
```

**Edit**: if requests are

1. *Both* borders are included (so `0.00` and `20.00` are valid)
2. There're *at most* two digits after the decimal point(`5`, `5.1`, `5.12` are valid, but `5.123` is not)
3. *Dangling dots* are not allowed (`5.` is not valid)
4. *Leading zeros* are invalid (so `05.00` is invalid)

the regular expression can be

```
(^1?[0-9](\.[0-9]{1,2})?$)|(^20(\.0{1,2})?$)
```

Comment: No 5 is also valid like it should handle both the scenario 5 & 5.00 or 5.89 etc

Comment: @Bikram Sahu: But you've put "I require only **exactly 2 digits** after decimal point". So what about `5.1` is it a valid input? And what about `5.` (note the dot, please)

Comment: Yes It is the valid input. Anyway Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: `^(1?\d(?:\.\d{1,2})?|20(?:\.00?)?)$` would be a bit simpler don't you think?

Comment: @Thomas: `\d` allows *any* digit, including, say, Persian ones: `۰ ۱ ۲ ۳ ۴ ۵ ۶`; when `[0-9]` matches exactly `0..9` range

Comment: OP never told us that he won't match Persian numbers...