# RegEx Absolute number greater than or equal to 120

Tags: regex

I have a string with a value that ranges from any negative number to any positive number. I only want to match on the absolute value of that number equal to or greater than 120.

Ex. I have -843 I need to know if that number is greater than 120.
Ex. I have 1002 I need to know if that number is greater than 120.
Ex. I have 22, no match.
Ex. I have -119, no match.

I started working this but got stuck after 3 digits. The number can be any number.

```
.*([1-9][2-9]\d)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/SU6Znr/1

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27499109/3832970. There is a link to the Python code that generates such regexps for you. And there is another link on that page to a better Python code.

Comment: Link requires a password, this is not helpful.

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/534137-generate-a-regular-expression-to-match-an-arbitrar/ does not require any password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

```
^(-?(?:1[2-9]\d|[2-9]\d\d|[1-9]\d{3,}))$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` start of the string
- `-?` in order to accept negative values
- `1[2-9]\d` any value between 120 and 199
- `[2-9]\d\d` any value between 200 and 999
- `[1-9]\d{3,}` any 4+ digits number starting with `1`
- `$` end of the string

#### [Test it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SU6Znr/5)

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use 2 cases in your regex: one for when the number is exactly three digits, and one for when the number is more than three digits. You'll want to remove the `.*` at the beginning of the regex because it matches anything, including non-digits.

You can use:

`^(-|)([1-9][2-9]\d|[1-9]\d{3,})$`

The regex has beginning/ending anchors to make sure you're checking the entire string. The first OR condition checks for a negative sign. Assuming there are no leading zeros, `[1-9][2-9]\d` checks for a 3 digit number greater than or equal to 120, and `[1-9]\d{3,}` checks for a number at least 4 digits long.

EDIT:

My regex failed to validate some three digit numbers, such as `200`. The best regex is the one accepted above:

`^(-?(?:1[2-9]\d|[2-9]\d\d|[1-9]\d{3,}))$`

Comment: This will reject `200` and many other valid numbers. Also, an optional minus sign should be matched using `-?`, not with alternation.

Comment: @TimPietzcker you're right, that case went over my head. I edited my answer to include the accepted regex, so that my answer doesn't remain incorrect (although I left the incorrect regex to see my train of thought). I appreciate the comment!