# Regular expression for checking a number range (with decimals)

Tags: c#, regex, numbers

I am working on a window form which accepts certain range of value as input. So far, I could only find the range between `0` and `20000`.

```
(20000|[0-9]|0[1-9]|[1-9]\d{0,3})$
```

Can somebody kindly help me with finding the range between `0.0` and `20479.0` (including decimals)?

Comment: What have you tried doing? (Also why do you need a regular expression for this?)

Comment: do a simple comparison - a constant or configurable numeric value is easier to maintain than the obscure, specialized regex this would become: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22131040/1132334

Comment: Yes, regular expression are probably not your first choice here and overly complicating the problem

Comment: @dlatikay mine input has some characters too in it like VB0.0-VB20479.0

Comment: So the number can start with arbitrary characters? And - do you want the regex to match a range, i.e. "number hyphen number"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion that allows numbers between 0 and 20479 with decimals:

```
^(0?[0-9]{0,4}(?:\.\d+)?|1\d{4}(?:\.\d+)?|20[0-4][0-7][0-8](?:\.\d+)?|20479(?:\.[0-7])?)$
```

As you can see, it is a bit complex, you may not want to do it with a regex.

## [Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cfOrBN/2)

**Explanation**

- `(0?[0-9]{0,4}(?:\.\d+)?` between 0.0 and 9999.99 (decimals are optional)
- `1\d{4}(?:\.\d+)?` between 10000.0 and 19999.99 (decimals are optional)
- `20[0-4][0-7][0-8](?:\.\d+)?` between 20000.0 and 2048.99 (decimals are optional)
- `20479(?:\.[0-7])?` between 20479 and 20479.7

---

**Update:** Without decimals, you can use:

```
^(0?[0-9]{0,4}|1\d{4}|20[0-4][0-7][0-8]|20479$
```

Comment: M really sorry but i wanted the range to be specifically from 0.0-0.7 till 20479.0-20479.7 which means i dont want the range exceeding above .7 at decimal place
eg- 1.7-20479.7

Comment: thanks a lot it worked well. And also you could help me without decimal of the same range.

Comment: @Punk Glad I helped. Could you *accept* the answer if it solved your issue? (the mark under the score at the left of the answer). I've also updated my answer to provide you another regex without decimals.

Comment: ohh m really sorry i forgot... upvoted !!!  And also you could help me without decimal of same range please ..

Comment: Apart from have worse performance than the one in my answer ;) it also matches empty rows. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1):

As comments suggest, regex is far from ideal in these cases. It can be done though, but get quite complex.

```
^(?:(?:1?\d{1,4}|20[0-3]\d\d|204[0-6]\d|2047[0-8])(?:\.\d+)?|20479(?:\.0+)?)$
```

This does it using two outer alternations - one to match the maximum number and optionally any number of zeroes as decimals. The other (first) has several sub-alternations matching the maximum for the different digits, and allowing an optional decimal point and decimals.

```
1?\d{1,4}     Matches 0-19999
20[0-3]\d\d   Matches 20000-20399
204[0-6]\d    Matches 20400-20469
2047[0-8]     Matches 20470-20478
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XwCof0/2).

Comment: `1?\d{1,4}` matches even [`६` devanagari digit six](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/096c/index.htm)... :-)

Comment: @xanatos It appears that is true for regex in **python**, which isn't the case here. (And I petty you for all the comments you'll have to leave here on SO if you're to inform all post authors of that fact ;).)

Comment: It is true for .NET (and so for C#)... And my mission in life is to tell it one programmer at a time :-)

Comment: @xanatos :O Thanks for the info. Did not know that. (That'll be really helpful to everyone mixing devanāgarī digits with arabic by mistake ;) )

Answer (score 0):

If you expect only integers (.0 at the end) you could try [this](https://regex101.com/r/LvntnI/1/)

Mask is

```
^((1?[0-9]{0,4})|((20(([0-3][0-9]{0,2})|(4[0-7][0-9])))))$
```

If you need .0 at the end add `\.0` before `$`. If you need double/decimal than precision/range would be required.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a regex that'll be hardly maintainable when you can use real code:

```
public bool IsValid(string input = "")
{
    double inputParsed;
    if (!double.TryParse(input, out inputParsed))
        return false;

    if(inputParsed < 0 || inputParsed > 20479)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex get two numbers before and after the point.
Then check the numbers to hit the range.

```
var list = new List<string> { "VB0.0", "VB20479.0", "VB20479.7", "VB20480.0", "VB010000.0", "VB0.8", "VBx.y" };

string pattern = @"(\d+)\.(\d+)";

foreach (var input in list)
{
    var m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

    if (m.Success)
    {
        string value1 = m.Groups[1].Value;
        string value2 = m.Groups[2].Value;

        bool result = value1.Length <= 5 && int.Parse(value1) <= 20479
                   && value2.Length <= 1 && int.Parse(value2) <= 7;

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
    else Console.WriteLine(false);
}
```