# MySQL select from text column with specification

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I would like to query a database which is MySQL 5.

Let's say database name is `db` and the table name is `table` and the column name is `column`

and that column is a `text`

**containing the following for example:**

```
aksksksksjsjk&ct=100&lor=10
aksksksksjsjk&ct=1001001001001001&lor=10
```

So i would like to query that table and grep only where `ct` start with number `1` and it's `16` numbers.

I tried with `SELECT column FROM db.table WHERE column LIKE '%ct=1%'`

so it's gonna grep where `ct` start with number `1`

so kindly try to help me to proceed with select `ct` when start with number `1` and contain 16 `numbers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its basic form, you might want to use

```
SELECT column FROM db.table WHERE column REGEXP BINARY 'ct=1[0-9]{15}'
```

Or, to match as a whole word:

```
SELECT column FROM db.table WHERE column REGEXP BINARY '[[:<:]]ct=1[0-9]{15}[[:>:]]'
```

Note that `[0-9]{15}` matches 15 digits.

The `BINARY` keyword will make matching case sensitive, so only `ct` will get matched and `CT` won't. Remove it if you need to keep the regex case insensitive.

The `[[:<:]]` matches the left-hand (starting) word boundary and `[[:>:]]` matches the trailing (end) word boundary.

Comment: Thank you so much. it's work. mind if i asked you another question? in case if the same text include `exp=0918` so are there's way to select `exp` bigger than `0918` ?

Comment: @DoumerIssac That is a [complex topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130429/using-regular-expressions-to-validate-a-numeric-range). However, using [the number range generator](http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/), you may try `0*(919|9[2-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{3,})`