# Can I used SED to replace a value within a range?

Tags: sed, substitution

I'm trying to replace a field with the proper value but I can't figure out how to do a blanket substitution. Here is what I have so far.

```
sed -i '' 's/AuthUserName=\[7000-8000]/AuthUserName=7325/g' "$f"
```

I'm trying to search all the files that contain `AuthUserName=7000-8000` and make them all say `AuthUserName=7325`. I can do it individually by just having the `AuthUserName=7000` for example and it will replace it with 7325 but I can't figure it out.

I tried to use =* but no success. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using regular expressions to validate a numeric range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130429/using-regular-expressions-to-validate-a-numeric-range)

Comment: `perl -pe 'm/AuthUserName=([0-9]+)/; s//AuthUserName=7325/ if $1 >= 7000 && $1 <= 8000' input`

Answer (score 0):

For the numbers `7000` up to `7999` you could use a regular expression like `7[0-9][0-9][0-9]`.  Where each `[0-9]` simply stands for "one single digit from 0-9".  You would then only have to treat the `8000` as a special case.

Comment: That makes a perfect sense. I tried AuthUserName=\7[0-9][0-9][0-9]/AuthUserName=7325 with no success. I am not too terribly familiar with regular expressions but I will do some studying after this problem. Mind showing me the proper syntax?

Comment: sed 's/AuthUserName=7[0-9][0-9][0-9]/AuthUserName=7325/g'

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
sed 's/AuthUserName=7[0-9][0-9][0-9]\|AuthUserName=8000/AuthUserName=7325/g'
```

or

```
sed 's/AuthUserName=7[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]\|AuthUserName=8000/AuthUserName=7325/g'
```

[0-9] or [[:digit:]] are equivalent.

\| expresses alternative expression

Comment: I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Using perl and *lookaround*. First a test file:

```
$ cat file
asd
asd AuthUserName=700
asd AuthUserName=7000
asd AuthUserName=8000
asd AuthUserName=9000
asd AuthUserName=70000
```

The perl one-liner:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<=AuthUserName=)(7[0-9]{3}|8000)(?![0-9])/7325/g' file
```

ie. *7000-8000 preceeded by `AuthUserName=` and not followed by a digit*, output:

```
asd
asd AuthUserName=700
asd AuthUserName=7325
asd AuthUserName=7325
asd AuthUserName=9000
asd AuthUserName=70000
```

In sed:

```
$ sed 's/\(AuthUserName=\)\(7[0-9]\{3\}\|8000\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\17325\3/g' file
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm not familiar with perl at all but i'm going to look into it now.