# How can develop regex iban code with number in this interval [02-98]?

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a control on the iban with the following characteristics :
- minimum 14 characters
- maximum 34 characters
- the first 2 characters are always two letters (country identifier)
- the 3rd and 4th characters always two digits (control keys (from 02 to 98)
I am trying to develop a simple REGEX in Java with pattern like that:

```
@Pattern(
    regexp = "[a-zA-Z]{2}([2-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-8]){2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[0-9]{6}([a-zA-Z0-9]?){0,20}", 
    message = "Le format de l'iban est invalide"
)
```

The problem for the 3rd and 4th character is that the system does not accept these conditions (10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90) although these numbers are included in the interval [ 02-98]

Comment: There is a utility for it mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27499109/3832970)

Comment: Sorry but it not worked for me

Comment: And what did you try? It can't fail to work. The patterns are accurate there.

Comment: I am trying to execute this regex code @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z]{2}([2-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-8]){2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[0-9]{6}([a-zA-Z0-9]?){0,20}", message = "Le format de l'iban est invalide")
from this site http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/                                the problem that 99 and 01 (the 3rd and 4th character)  is accepted

Comment: But you did not account for the fact that a single digit number should be preceded by a `0`. Otherwise, the number will be matched with the `[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}` pattern. Please update the question with this pattern since this is now making more sense.

Comment: Try `^[a-zA-Z]{2}(?:0[2-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-8])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[0-9]{6}[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,20}$`, see the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dvyQ4v/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}(?:0[2-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-8])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[0-9]{6}[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,20}$
```

The `([2-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-8]){2}` part is replaced with `(?:0[2-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-8])`. Your `([2-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-8]){2}` matches two occurrences of a digit between `2` and `9`, or two occurrences of numbers between 10 and 98. So, you need to add `0` to the first alternative and remove the `{2}` quantifier.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dvyQ4v/1/)

**Details**

- `^` -  start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]{2}` - two ASCII letters
- `(?:0[2-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-8])` - a number between `02` to `98`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}` - four ASCII alphanumeric chars
- `[0-9]{6}` - six digits
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,20}` - 0 to 20 ASCII alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.