# What is the regular expression for numbers between 10000000 and 29999999?

Tags: regex

I am not a programmer, but I use a system that sometimes requires  regex knowledge. I need a custom field on a sign up form on my website. The custom field is only numbers between 10000000 and 29999999. How would I write the expression?

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using regular expressions to validate a numeric range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130429/using-regular-expressions-to-validate-a-numeric-range). In the future please search for your answer before asking a question that has been asked before.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be something like this:

`^[12]\d{7}$`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nrJucc/1)

- `^` - Matches start of line. Ensuring the next match is the first character of the string.
- `[12]` - Checks if the first character is a 1 or 2.
- `\d{7}` - Ensures the next 7 characters are 0-9
- `$` - Matches the end of the line. This helps ensures there's nothing after the 7th character that we matched prior.