# Regular expression to validate Excel cell

Tags: php, regex, excel, expression, cell

I'm working on a php application where the user has to insert an Excel's cell id (for example `A1` or `AB32`), a value which is stored in the database for later use and I'm trying to validate the cell id format using a regular expression, but it just doesn't seem to be working, this is what I've got so far.

```
^[a-zA-Z]\d$
```

Comment: You need quantifiers if there can be multiples. `[a-zA-Z]+` will allow `AB`, or `A`, or `aBc`, etc. `\d+` will allow `1`, `32`, `333`, etc. You can use regex101 to test, https://regex101.com/r/8OQVBs/1, with update https://regex101.com/r/8OQVBs/2

Comment: Use `^[a-zA-Z]+\d+$` or even `^[a-zA-Z]+\d+\z`

Comment: BTW, I have checked: in my Excel, I have max 1048576 rows and `XFD` columns. This might not be that easy with a regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I had a go - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There's an awesome [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710236/function-to-create-regex-matching-a-number-range) in this question by @BartKiers where he builds a function to construct these type of regexes that need to match ranges of x to y. His logic transfers nicely to text ranges and is [tested in PCRE dialect](https://regex101.com/r/wRQDAh/1) at regex101.com.

The regex:

`^(?:[A-Z]|[A-Z][A-Z]|[A-X][A-F][A-D])(?:[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|10[0-3][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|104[0-7][0-9][0-9][0-9]|1048[0-4][0-9][0-9]|10485[0-6][0-9]|104857[0-6])$`

Which basically says:

- Columns part: `A-Z`, or `A-Z` with `A-Z`, or `A-X` with `A-F` with `A-D`
- Rows part: `1-9`, or `1-9` with `0-9`, or `1-9` with `1-9` with `0-9` etc all the way to the max of `104857` with `0-6`

It matches the following:

```
A1
AA11
AAA111
ZZ12
YY1048575
XFD1048576
```

It will not match the following:

```
A0
AA01
AAZ1111111
XFD1048577
XFE1048576
ZZZ333
ZZZ9999999
```

Here's the diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this `^[a-zA-Z]{1,4}(\d+)$`

- ^([a-zA-Z]+) : starting between 1 and 4 letters
- (\d+)$ : ending with one digit or more

Comment: How do you validate that the digit part is less than **1048577**??

Comment: How do you validate that the letter part has less than **4** letters??

Comment: I just updated my answer to check for a max of 4 letters.

But as long as i know regex is for strings, it can't evaluate values, and your constraint can't lead to a specific pattern that can be "easily" implemented as an expression. 

you can try to split you max limit 1048577 to many conditions (1 or nothing), (0 to 9 or noting) ... but event this way you can't get exactly the correct limit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `^([A-Z]{1,3})([1-9]\d{0,6})$`

or A1 ~ XDF1048576:

```
"^(?:[A-Z]{1,2}|" +                  // A   - ZZ
"[A-W][A-Z][A-Z]|" +                 // AAA - WZZ
"X[A-E][A-Z]|" +                     // XAA - XEZ
"XF[A-D])" +                         // XFA - XFD
"(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,5}|" +              // 1       - 999999
"10[0-3][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|" +     // 1000000 - 1039999
"104[0-7][0-9][0-9][0-9]|" +         // 1040000 - 1047999
"1048[0-4][0-9][0-9]|" +             // 1048000 - 1048499
"10485[0-6][0-9]|" +                 // 1048500 - 1048569
"104857[0-6])$"                      // 1048570 - 1048576
```