# Regular expression for an Excel cell with R1C1 notation

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I need some code to test if a cell contains a formula with a reference to another cell.

I found the answer [Find all used references in Excel formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33146900) but the solution matches wrongly also formula with references to table columns as :

```
=SearchValInCol2(Tabella1[articolo];[@articolo];Tabella1[b])
```

Then, I wrote the following VBA code using the **Like** operator, but surely a solution with a regular expression would be more solid (I think the following code won't work in many scenarios).

```
Private Function TestIfCellContainsAFormula(cellToTest As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim result As Object
    Dim r As Range
    Dim testExpression As String
    Dim objRegEx As Object

    Set r = cellToTest  ' INPUT THE CELL HERE , e.g.    RANGE("A1")
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegEx.Global = True
    objRegEx.Pattern = """.*?"""  ' remove expressions
    testExpression = CStr(r.FormulaR1C1)

    ' search for pattern "=R[-3]C+4"
    If testExpression Like "*R[[]*[]]*C*" Then
        TestIfCellContainsAFormula2 = True
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' search for pattern "=RC[2]"
    If testExpression Like "*R*C[[]*[]]*" Then
    'If InStr(1, testExpression, "C[", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        TestIfCellContainsAFormula2 = True
        Exit Function
    End If

    TestIfCellContainsAFormula2 = False

End Function
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/r196Nz/2

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/r196Nz/3

Comment: Is that what your looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1

To match R1C1 style references you can use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/lmvZVt/1):

```
R(\[-?\d+\])C(\[-?\d+\])|R(\[-?\d+\])C|RC(\[-?\d+\])
```

See the [railroad](https://regexper.com/#R(%5C%5B-%3F%5Cd%2B%5C%5D)C(%5C%5B-%3F%5Cd%2B%5C%5D)%7CR(%5C%5B-%3F%5Cd%2B%5C%5D)C%7CRC(%5C%5B-%3F%5Cd%2B%5C%5D)) diagram for a visual explanation:

[image]

At the core is the 'offset' which is  `-?\d+` which is optional `-` followed by a digit or more. This sequence goes in the brackets (`[]`) to give `\[-?\d+\]`. Then the regex allows combinations of:

- `R[offset]C[offset]`
- `R[offset]C` or (`|`)
- `RC[offset]` or (`|`)

### Option 2

The regex above won't match `R`, `C`, or `RC`. It will match `R[0]`, `C[0]`, `R[0]C`, `RC[0]`, and `R[0]C[0]` which are kind of equivalent. To eliminate those matches you might use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/Ql0YXr/1):

```
R(\[-?[1-9][0-9]*\])C(\[-?[1-9][0-9]*\])|R(\[-?[1-9][0-9]*\])C|RC(\[-?[1-9][0-9]*\])
```

Which is this:[image]

But it seems entering `R[0]`, `C[0]` and `R[0]C[0]` in my Excel (v2013) turns them into `R`, `C` and `RC` anyways - so you can avoid the additional complexity if this is not a concern.

### Option 3

If you want to allow `R`, `C` and `RC` you can use a simpler regex:

```
R(\[-?\d+\])?C(\[-?\d+\])?
```

### VBA test code

This uses Option 1.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim varTests As Variant
    Dim varTest As Variant
    Dim varMatches As Variant
    Dim varMatch As Variant

    varTests = Array("RC", _
        "R[1]C", _
        "RC[1]", _
        "R[1]C[1]", _
        "R[-1]C", _
        "RC[-1]", _
        "R[-1]C[-1]", _
        "=SUM(A1:B2)", _
        "RC[1]+R[-1]C+R[2]C[-99]", _
        "R[-1]C-R[1]C[-44]-RC[999]+R[0]C[0]", _
        "SearchValInCol2(Tabella1[articolo];[@articolo];Tabella1[b])")

    For Each varTest In varTests
        varMatches = FormulaContainsR1C1Reference(CStr(varTest))
        Debug.Print "Input: " & CStr(varTest)
        Debug.Print VBA.String(Len(CStr(varTest)) + 7, "-")

        If IsEmpty(varMatches) Then
            Debug.Print "No matches"
        Else
            Debug.Print UBound(varMatches) & " matches"
            For Each varMatch In varMatches
                Debug.Print varMatch
            Next varMatch
        End If

        Debug.Print vbCrLf
    Next varTest

End Sub

Function FormulaContainsR1C1Reference(ByVal strFormula As String) As Variant

    Dim objRegex As Object
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim objMatches As Object
    Dim varMatches As Variant
    Dim lngCounter As Long

    Set objRegex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With objRegex
        ' setup regex
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "R(\[-?\d+\])C(\[-?\d+\])|R(\[-?\d+\])C|RC(\[-?\d+\])"

        ' get matches
        Set objMatches = .Execute(strFormula)

        ' iterate matches
        If objMatches.Count > 0 Then
            ReDim varMatches(1 To objMatches.Count)
            For lngCounter = 1 To objMatches.Count
                varMatches(lngCounter) = objMatches.Item(lngCounter - 1)
            Next lngCounter
        Else
            varMatches = Empty
        End If

    End With

    FormulaContainsR1C1Reference = varMatches

End Function
```

### A1 style references

I posted a regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347381/regular-expression-to-validate-excel-cell/42224197#42224197) for A1 style references:

`^(?:[A-Z]|[A-Z][A-Z]|[A-X][A-F][A-D])(?:[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|10[0-3][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|104[0-7][0-9][0-9][0-9]|1048[0-4][0-9][0-9]|10485[0-6][0-9]|104857[0-6])$`